# How to get the "real" category of a place while searching for it

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I am currently creating a list of parking-facility places near my location to verify them via MSR (name,  category,... ).

I am using https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/discover/search?q=parking-facility to get the list of all places near my location.

The places only show the overall category parking-facility and not its real main/subcategories within "category".

Same problem while looking into the place itself:
https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/...

```
categories: [
{
id:parking-facility
title:Parking Facility
```

How do I get the real categories for a place? (parking-lot , parking-garage, only-parking,...)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the latest version of the API https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html ("Browse" endpoint) and then instead of filtering the results with a `q` or `name` parameter, use the `categories` parameter.

You can find out about all available categories here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-places/places-category-system-full.html
In your case, check the "8500 - Parking" categories.